# How to make a 100% wide horizontal slideshow similar to Vogue

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I'm trying to look for a tutorial on building a slideshow similar to the one that Vogue uses: http://www.vogue.com/

I need to use almost the same exact functionality, however the active slide in the middle will have cycle pagination to go to the next slide along with the arrows. It will also have HTML content within the main active slide. The slides next to it will be "greyed" out or shown to be disactive similar to what's on Vogue.

Anyone have any good suggestions on jquery tutorials I can use or plugins? Can this be done using jQuery cycle?

Comment: Takea  look at the jQuery cycle plugin. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Cycle, but I think the interaction/event model on

> http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/index.html

is more robust and would probably work better for this particular application.

Answer (score 0):

just some hints:
to change opacity:
in javascript:

```
yourelement.style.opactity = x/100; yourelement.style.filter="alpha(opacity=" + x + ")";
```

in css: you probably want to make divs containing the images and then apply the css

```
div.IMG_CONTAINER_SHOW{opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);}
div.IMG_CONTAINER_HIDE{opacity:.5;filter:alpha(opacity=50);}
```

and for making a a scrollable div you will have to play with js or jquery

suggestions:

make an outer container div with a specific width, this will be the window shown on the page
make an inner container div inside the outer with a larger width, which is equal to the total content of all the images within
fill this inner container with divs

use javascripts scrollLeft or jquery cycle or whatever works
and use one of the above opacity methods

make divs within the outermost container div with with css :

```
div.ARROW_LEFT{position:absolute;top:50%;left:100px;width:50px;height:50px;cursor:pointer;}
div.ARROW_RIGHT{position:absolute;top:50%;right:100px;width:50px;height:50px;cursor:pointer;}
```

and the html:

```
<div class='ARROW_LEFT' onClick='Yourjavascrpt fuunction'><img src='yourLTarrowimg' /></div>
<div class='ARROW_RIGHT' onClick='Yourjavascrpt fuunction'><img src='yourRTarrowimg' /></div>
```

you can refer to my tutorial, it is something a little  more complex but you can use parts of it if it helps: http://electrifiedpulseone.blogspot.com/

and here is it in action:
http://electrifiedpulse.com/pictures_.html